# How to get the length of a formatted string read in using fscanf in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I am reading a text file which has string test cases and decode them to process as Verilog test constructs to simulate. The code that I use to read a file is as follows:

```
integer pntr,file;
string a,b,c,d;
initial 
  begin
    pntr = $fopen(FOO, "r");
  end
always
  begin

    if(!$feof(pntr))
      begin
        file = $fscanf(pntr, "%s %s %s %s \n", a,b,c,d);
      end
    else
       $fclose(pntr);
```

I have tried using

```
integer k;
k = strlen($fscanf(pntr, "%s %s %s %s \n", a,b,c,d));
$display(k);
```

and the display statement outputs an "x"
I also tried using

```
$display(file)
```

but this also gives me x as the display output. The above code is just a representation of my problem, I am using a larger formatted string to read in larger data. Each line of my testcase may have different size. I have initialized the format to the maximum number of string literals that my testcase can have. I wanted to ask if there is a way to get the length of each line that I read or number of string literals that fscanf read ?
Note: I am using Cadence tools for this task.
Input file looks like

```
read reg_loc1
write regloc2 2.5V regloc3 20mA
read regloc3 regloc5 regloc7
```

Comment: The input file will be read in and each string literal will be converted to an equivalent instruction. for example if I take 1st instruction in input file, read will enable an output function and reg_loc1 is converted to a net-name which needs to be probed. For my input file, I want to output to be 2, 5 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug your code when you have lots of typos and incomplete code. And you also have a race condition in that `pntr` may not have been assigned from `$fopen` if the `always` block executes before the `initial` block.

But in any case, the problem with using `$fscanf` and the `%s` format is that a *newline* gets treated as whitespace. It's better to use `$fgets` to read a line at a time, and the use `$sscanf` to parse the line:

```
module top;
  
  integer pntr,file;
  string a,b,c,d, line;
  initial  begin
    pntr = $fopen("FOO", "r");
    while(!$feof(pntr))
      if ((file = $fgets(line,pntr)!=0)) begin
        $write("%d line: ", file, line);
        file = $sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s \n", a,b,c,d);
        $display(file,,a,b,,c,,d);
      end
      $fclose(pntr);
  end
endmodule
```